# Disable whole user control focusing from keyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, focus

I have UserControl in a window. When user walks window with "Tab" key user control gets focused and dashed border drawn around it. How to prevent this behavior?
[image]

Comment: Try it for element, that shifts the focus, set the `Focusable = False`.

Comment: Only as curiosity... Try to put the same tab as, maybe, your first TextBox, and then put on your TextBox IsTabStop="True". I haven't tried, but I'm fighting against something similar right now.
Focusable = false; IsTabStop=false; Have you tried these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I had xaml:

```
<ContentControl>
  <ScrollViewer name="viewport"/>
</ContentControl>
```

and "viewport.Content" was set to my UserControl from code-behind.

It was a ContentControl who draw the focus border. I removed it and left only a . Problem solved.

Answer (score 8):

Try it for an control set `Focusable = "False"`. Example:

```
<Grid Focusable="False">
...
</Grid>
```

Or set the `Style` to focus yourself:

```
<Grid FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
```

Also, the `Style` of focus might be:

```
<Style x:Key="MyItemFocusVisual" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="#7B2F81" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Using:

```
<Grid Focusable="True" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource MyItemFocusVisual}" ... />
```

`Output`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to keep it from accepting focus via Tabbing just declare it on the object via `IsTabStop="False"` or you can edit the control Template for it and get rid of the Focus changes.

Comment: Hmm then there's something else going on here. Did you apply the IsTabStop to the usercontrol itself, or the tag you're populating your window with? Maybe share some code?